# Row reading issue in csv containing html format data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, data-science

I have one html file containing a table in it. Total rows in the tables are around 3500. I want to read and print rows with same values. PFA Image of the html data. 
[image]
I transform the data into csv where I could see same data in html format.
As shown in image. I want to print and write all the rows containing "MyData" to another CSV and then need to mail it.
I tried using **Soupbeautiful** but not able to get the result.
I tried using CSV and Pandas but it is not returning the expected output.
My python code is as follows;

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)    
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')    
data = print (df.iloc[0:5])
```

Another code I tried

```
search_string = "MyData"
 with open('test.csv') as f, open('test2.csv', 'w') as g:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None) # discard the header
    writer = csv.writer(g)
    for row in reader:
        if row[2] == search_string:
            writer.writerow(row[:2])
            print(row)
```

When I enter complete row from **info_data** then it gives me that particular row but not other rows where the string "MyData" is present. 
Thanks !

Comment: `print()` always return `None` so code `data = print (df.iloc[0:5])`  means `data = None`. You need `data = df.iloc[0:5]`

Comment: `df[ df["Info_data"].str.contains("MyData") ].to_csf("output.csv")` ? But only if you have strings in `Info_data`, not list with string.

Comment: Put data as text - or better create minimal working code with data so we could run it.

Comment: Try `if search_string in row[2]:` as you are currently looking for an exact match

Answer (score 0):

You are currently testing the entry for an exact match with your search string. That entry contains a JSON string, so you could use `in` to see if it contains `search_string` rather than is an exact match for it, for example:

```
search_string = "MyData"

with open('test.csv') as f, open('test2.csv', 'w') as g:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None) # discard the header
    writer = csv.writer(g)

    for row in reader:
        if search_string in row[2]:
            writer.writerow(row[:2])
            print(row)
```

You would then want to add code to further decode you JSON data.